# productsign still ask for password even keychain unlocked and cert given permission on import

Tags: macos, certificate, code-signing

I am trying to automate `productsign` of my pkg installer.

On `security import` I gave `productsign` access

`security import ${P12_PATH} -f 'pkcs12' -k ${KEYCHAIN_NAME} -P ${P12_INSTALLER_PASSWORD} -T /usr/bin/productsign`

I can also see from keychain that `productsign` has been given the access
[image]

But when I try to sign the pkg, the computer still popup and ask for the keychain password to access the key.

```
security unlock-keychain -p ${KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD} ${KEYCHAIN_NAME}
/usr/bin/productsign --timestamp --keychain ${KEYCHAIN_NAME} --sign 'Developer ID Installer: xxxx' ${binary_path} signed.pkg
```

[image]

Any suggestion what I did wrong? How can I `productsign` without prompting any password input.

Comment: Any updates on this one?